# Why isn't the static variable getting modified

Tags: c++, static

I'm creating a static variable 'a' inside a member function getobj() and returning it by reference and capture the reference in b. And  I modify the same static variable 'a' in another member function mod(). When I print b, I should be expecting '2' right? Why isn't the static variable 'a' not modified to 2?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
  
  public:
  int& getobj() {
    static int a = 1;
    return a;
  }

  void mod() {
    static int a = 2;
  }

};

int main(int arc, char* args[]) {

  Test t;
  int &b = t.getobj();
  cout << "printing b first time and its value is expected : " << b << endl;
  t.mod();
  cout << "printing b second time after modifying and its value has not changed : " << b << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output observed is

```
printing b first time and its value is expected : 1
printing b second time after modifying and its value has not changed : 1
```

Comment: if you want to have a unique *a* make it a class variable, add `static int a;`in class definition and remove `static int` in the existing definitions

Answer (score 5):

The variable `a` in `getobj()` and the variable `a` in `mod()` are in different scope and are different things.

Therefore, modification to `a` in `mod()` won't affect `a` in `getobj()`.

Comment: But, it's marked static. And variables marked with static are stored in static area. So, aren't they sort of global scope.?

Comment: @SriramNagaraj it is not static for the class but for each methods. As I said in a remark if you want to have a unique *a* make it a class variable, add `static int a;`in class definition and remove `static int` in the methods

Comment: No, they are not in global scope. Rooms for each `a` will be allocated in static area.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve your aim with the following piece of computational devilry:

```
void mod() {
    static int& a = getobj();
    a = 2;
}
```

Currently you have two different `int`s, both with `static` storage. Changing one will not change the other.

But did you want to use a class member variable instead (which is the normal thing to do), perhaps even without `static` storage duration?